# Assets default to HTTPS on localhost

Tags: http, ssl, browser, https, localhost

When I load my web app via localhost (which is not served via HTTPS), I find that the CSS and JavaScript assets fail to load, because the browser tries to access them via `https://localhost:3000/style.css` and `https://localhost:3000/script.js`. The website itself (`index.html`) is served via HTTP.

In the document `<head>`, both assets are included via their relative path, so the browser must be defaulting to HTTPS to retrieve all assets.

I already checked the HSTS setting on my server and made sure that it is turned off during development. I also cleared the HSTS cache in my browser, to no avail.

Any pointers to where I should look next would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out — apparently, a recent update to [Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) impacted two settings:

- HSTS
- Content-Security-Policy

When disabling *both* (in development), *and* after resetting the browser HSTS cache, everything worked as expected again.